# copying a windows program to another machine

Tags: windows, copy

I have a program installed on windows 7 in my laptop. I wish to install the same program on windows 7 in my desktop. unfortunately, I don't have the source file with me anymore. How can I copy the entire program from one machine to another machine and make it run?

Comment: You may want to ask this on SuperUser :)

Comment: What is the problem ? Why don't you just copy the entire folder of your application from your laptop to your desktop ? The only inconvenient is that it won't be built to fit to your system, but I think it will work the same, no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the program if that's possible or not.

You would have to know, which parts the installer copied to your computer and to which directories. Even then it is possible that the installer checked for prerequisites, found them on the laptop, but are missing on the desktop computer.

You can try to copy the files from the %ProgramFiles% directory, but it is poor luck if that works and you can't be sure that it works correctly. So your best option is to organise the installer package again.

Comment: copied the files.. no luck.. it asked for dll files, which one by one I copied. still it failed to run. what else can be tried?

Comment: I cannot tell, you would have to know what the installer does. Some DLL's have to be registered, maybe some registry settings are necessary, copy protection can have an influence... A setup can be as easy as to copy a file, or as complicated that you need a program only to install the software.

Answer (score 1):

see [How to Copy a Program From One Computer to Another Without a Startup Disk](http://www.ehow.com/how_5061188_copy-computer-another-startup-disk.html).I hope it will work.